# First author submits manuscript before final approval of all co-authors

Tags: publications, paper-submission, authorship

A **first and corresponding** author has submitted a co-authored manuscript after having circulated a near-final draft. She has freely accepted some comments of her colleagues' and rebutted others, but only shared the final version after submission. This is despite some co-authors specifically asked to view the very last version once more before the submission.

The manuscript is for a normal issue of a peer-reviewed journal. The referees' comments have been dealt with. All kinks concerning methodology, results and conclusions had already been ironed out. The remaining comments were of linguistic/stylistic/presentational nature alone and improved the readability of the paper appreciably. For example: removing repetitions, streamlining the content, splitting paragraphs into block of homogeneous content, and so forth. Let's regard these interventions as important for the standing of the paper --- see [this guide of Elsevier's](http://www.publishingcampus.elsevier.com/websites/elsevier_publishingcampus/files/Skills%20training/Elements_of_Style.pdf) for a general appreciation of why linguistic editing is relevant to proper scientific writing. *In other situations where 'heavier' matters of content might have been at stake, this post's concerns would hold nonetheless.*

The reasons for not circulating the final version are a self-imposed deadline, tied up to office holidays, and the reasoning that the time for applying linguistic changes is over. This latter point is immediately questionable since the bulk of polishing takes place at the end of writing, almost by definition.

Within the authors' team, two lines of thought emerge as to whether the first author ought to share the final manuscript before definitive submission. Some say that the first author has the authority of moving on; others say that the first author should not submit without giving her colleagues the possibility of seeing what happened of the last remarks.

The journal's authorship guidelines are curt. 
*Note that the journal is not interested in authorship ranking that are internal to the group; it only deals with the roles taken by one author as correspondent.*
Quoting the most relevant ones, these boil down to the following:

- to be such, all authors must meet *all of the following requirements* a) providing substantial contributions b) drafting or revising the work c) giving final approval of the version to be submitted for publication;
- the responsibility of the **corresponding author** is to dialogue with the co-authors and act on their behalf.

There is an interesting paradox in this formulation. A **corresponding** author will invariably act on behalf of people who have approved the manuscript, *whether all collaborators have been asked or not*. Those who do not approve are, or may fear to become, no co-authors. The first author can easily find leeway to disregard some collaborators, and move on with the submission with a malformed sense of entitlement. Co-authors may easily lose the aegis of the first author.

Say. The colleagues who demand a last glance at the final manuscript may face a rejection in the line of "co-authors only suggest, first author decides". This could be rebutted with something like "the first author is not fully acting on our behalf, though; she fails in acting as  corresponding author". Then, the challenge could be "you are missing the point on the way it works; she's the first author, do you really want to be co-authors?". The first author thanks and submits, some co-authors only see the show. 
Further discussion is deterred by the fact that, once the manuscript has been submitted, the situation can only be reversed by summoning up the editor. This step might be felt as overly confrontational, and the authorship guidelines above may not help the editor much either.

**My question is: does the first/corresponding author have an obligation not to proceed with submission of a manuscript before having given *all* co-authors the final say to what will be submitted?**

Comment: Usually the matter of _[t]hose who do not approve are, or may fear to become, no co-authors_ is prevented by an addition to journal guidelines along the lines that 'those rules are not be used to deny authorship where authorship is due'.

Comment: How much time left before the conference deadline did you have?

Comment: @Clément Added that "The manuscript is for a normal issue of a peer-reviewed journal. The referees' comments have been dealt with"

Comment: @XavierStuvw I tried to make the question (the way I understand it) clearer and stand out a bit. Feel free to change/roll back if you disagree.

Comment: Sounds pretty dysfunctional. I know I find it annoying when co-authors want to nitpick on style preferences. But I imagine it could go either way depending on who is being the more unreasonable. Is this a field where first authorship is significantly more important than the others?

Comment: "giving final approval of the version to be submitted for publication" -- that guideline from the journal seems entirely straightforward. This question seems like a complicated word-game to try to weasel out of that.

Comment: @Mark Fine, the change respects the original intent

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm Let's assume that it is not nitpicking, but a due regular grammar and style check as language editors do. We could also regard the nature of the last edit immaterial with respect to the nature of the corresponding author's behaviour. Re your question, in this particular case, authorship order implies some ranking in the involvement in the underlying research; nonetheless we could assume that the authors are in alphabetical order, and the first author is just the corresponding author regardless of where the alphabet places her.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins There is indeed some complication arising from the social game around this situation. In particular, there is a concern that authors can be discouraged from being vocal, for fear of being ostracised or isolated as nitpickers. The question is perhaps more about the role that the first author may take in counting in who is approving, and counting out who is not. The word game could be used by a first author to reinforce her entitlement to lead the (internal, external) reviewing and proof-reading processes in a single-minded way. Note this may be a matter of office/group culture.

Comment: @XavierStuvw First authorship and equal authorship are two very different situations. In the former, no one will fault a co-author for the primary author's use of an oxford comma or dopey title, so I'd say it's overreaching to claim control over such decisions (unless they're an adviser or something like that). Of course, I have trouble imagining how style could be anything but nitpicking. Can you give an example? Equal authorship meanwhile is not something I deal with.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm To identify style issues and their relevance for a scientific paper I'd borrow [this guideline from Elsevier](http://www.publishingcampus.elsevier.com/websites/elsevier_publishingcampus/files/Skills%20training/Elements_of_Style.pdf). As mentioned, the crux is that the submission of the manuscript without consent of some co-authors; that the final manuscript differed from the final draft for style matters is incidental. Rather, you bring up a distinction between authors ranking and the role of corresponding authors, I'll edit the post. Would you elaborate on this in an answer?

Comment: The Elsevier guide is gone?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Apparently yes, at least for the moment. It goes about "Elements of Style for Writing Scientific Journal Articles" by Stephen M. Griffies, William A. Perrie, Gaëlle Hull  -- currently one other copy is available from https://elireview.com/content/curriculum/imrad/elements-of-style-journal-articles.pdf

Comment: @XavierStuvw Thanks! They must be eager to remove useful information, consistent with their "no free drink policy" :)
https://gitlab.com/publishing-reform/discussion/issues/104

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An article should not be submitted to a journal (or otherwise distributed) without the explicit approval of all the authors. All authors can be held responsible for the contents of the article: errors or frauds committed by the first author can be blamed on the other authors as well. (Remember [Yoshiki Sasai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshiki_Sasai).)

This said, as a matter of convenience, some authors may give their go-ahead in advance and/or without seeing the last version, if they sufficiently trust the first author. Still, they should say it explicitly.